# Can I use Panel Data for just two countries?

Tags: regression, panel-data

I'm looking to compare the German and Spanish labour markets throughout the Great Recession and how the interactions with shocks and institutions effected their different labour market outcomes. I am going to be using the Blanchard and Wolfers Model (2000) with the dependent variables being the labour market institutions and the shocks and the independent being unemployment.

My question is, can I do this with just 2 countries worth of data of the years 1999-2016 ?

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].